# Does Darwin/Quicktime Streaming Server follow symlinks?

Tags: apple, video-streaming, video

I have DSS running quite happily on a Macmini using the default media folder (/Library/QuickTimeStreaming/Movies). However, I want to be able to stream video located in a different directory.

I've tried creating symlinks in the default media folder to the files that I want to stream but this doesn't work. I've also tried changing the configuration so that the media folder in DSS points at the directory that has all of my videos in it. Again, this doesn't work. In both instances any attempt to access any of the media results in a 404 error in the StreamingServer log and on the client.

Does DSS have a problem with symlinks? Or is the problem arising because my media is actually on a network share?

Answer (score 1):

Create a new folder on the QuickTimeStreaming server folder in the library and choose any name for the  folder.

Change to the media directory in DSS, `/Library/QuickTimeStreaming/Movies/ to /Library/QuickTimeStreaming/mp4/.`

Finish all of that and save the changes.
The "save" button is displayed at the bottom of the general settings page.
If you do not save, this won't work.
Move the videos to the new folder enjoy watching the stream.